# MapBox GL JS Combining Filters

Tags: mapbox-gl-js

I am trying to combine multiple filters on MapBox GL JS v1.9.1. The filter is -- if property "d" is between 2 integers AND property "i" has one of the given values AND if the point falls within a Polygon. The filter expression is as follows -

```
[
  "all",
  [
    ">=",
    [
      "get",
      "d"
    ],
    1577854800
  ],
  [
    "<=",
    [
      "get",
      "d"
    ],
    1577941199
  ],
  [
    "match",
    [
      "get",
      "i"
    ],
    [
      "bdba680267591d0543072cf18cd98e57",
      "c42c6d59e302b45e5fb6be6e8abdfcbb",
      "2b34c7d0c8fe7021eae2cf8b693f6d14",
      "bcbce48c922fdd706094d80f6f6efa5a"
    ],
    true,
    false
  ],
  [
    "==",
    [
      "within",
      [
        "object",
        {
          "type": "FeatureCollection",
          "features": [
            {
              "type": "Feature",
              "geometry": {
                "type": "Polygon",
                "coordinates": [
                  [
                    [
                      -73.96644912936983,
                      40.7579747
                    ],
                    [
                      -73.96790253328018,
                      40.76354671807032
                    ],
                    [
                      -73.96870366224104,
                      40.76483841792908
                    ],
                    [
                      -73.98926755133365,
                      40.77225531118752
                    ],
                    [
                      -73.99108514195954,
                      40.771908119615176
                    ],
                    [
                      -73.99284935487653,
                      40.77142674159516
                    ],
                    [
                      -73.99454319974974,
                      40.77081581306094
                    ],
                    [
                      -73.99615036392716,
                      40.770081217588285
                    ],
                    [
                      -74.00454413035031,
                      40.75940186729005
                    ],
                    [
                      -74.00463607063017,
                      40.7579747
                    ],
                    [
                      -73.97078314761191,
                      40.74873768960421
                    ],
                    [
                      -73.96966695937762,
                      40.749885383567914
                    ],
                    [
                      -73.96870366224104,
                      40.75111098207092
                    ],
                    [
                      -73.96790253328018,
                      40.752402681929674
                    ],
                    [
                      -73.96727128780488,
                      40.753748043368425
                    ],
                    [
                      -73.96681600505411,
                      40.75513410982106
                    ],
                    [
                      -73.9665410696497,
                      40.756547532709945
                    ],
                    [
                      -73.96644912936983,
                      40.7579747
                    ]
                  ]
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    ],
    true
  ]
]
```

The filter does not apply but if I remove "within" from the expression, the filter works fine. The "within" expression works perfectly just on its own as well but fails in the above case.

Any insights on how to solve this?

Comment: I don't know. But the `["==", ..., true]` is redundant. You could just put the middle expression.

Comment: I tried without the ['==' ... ] as well. But no luck. I think that 'within' is not included in the combination feature (yet).

Comment: Worth filing a bug report perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nested 'within' filter was [a bug](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/9605) and fixed.